# Using rigify, Automatic weights parenting fails

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify

I'm doing a basic human rig for practice. All of my bones are set up and the rig generates just fine, however, when I try to parent to the rig with auto weights, a majority of my mesh disappears (See pictures) [image]

[image]

Any ideas on what's happening?

Comment: You have drivers that are disabled, try to reload trusted, maybe that will fix the problem if they used on the rig?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It shows the error on the top of your screen, click reload trusted to reload the file, not sure that it is the problem though.

Comment: Oh duh didn't even see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Rigify work properly you need to enable running python scripts or scripted expressions. When opening your file click on **Reload Trusted** button on the top of blender screen.

[image]